# angle between leg and diagonal of isosceles trapezoid given ratio of bases and angle between opposite leg and diagonal

Tags: geometry

It seems to me this shouldn't be a hard question, but for some reason it's just not coming to me.

Given for an isosceles trapezoid the ratio of bases $\frac{AB}{CD}=R$ and the angle $\angle ADB$ between leg $AB$ and the diagonal $BD$, (how) can one find the angle $\angle DBC$?

[image]

Comment: Do you know sine rule? If so, can you apply it to the 2 triangles?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that rule existed. I managed to find an answer, though I'm not sure it's quite correct. For some reason when modeling the geometry I find the answer should be $\pi$ minus the answer I found.

Comment: Yes, that was the approach I was thinking of. Remember that there are 2 solutions to $ \sin \theta = c > 0 $, so we still have to eliminate one of them

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to forget the sine rule it seems. :) Using the sine rule, one can write

$$ \frac{\sin(\angle ABD)}{AB} = \frac{\sin(\angle ABD)}{AD} $$
$$ \frac{\sin(\angle DBC)}{CD} = \frac{\sin(\angle CDB)}{BC} $$

Using that $AB=BC$ and that with Z angles one finds $\angle ABD = \angle CBD $, one finds

$$ \frac{\sin(\angle ABD)}{AB} = \frac{\sin(\angle DBC)}{CD} $$

$$ \sin(\angle DBC) = \frac{CD}{AB} \sin(\angle ABD) $$

$$ \angle DBC = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{R} \sin(\angle ABD)\right) $$